# Unable to start my Websphere server in Local RSA

Tags: rsa, websphere-6.1

I am using WAS 6.1 and my server used to start properly but all of a sudden its not working..

when I attempt to start my server in my local RSA. I am getting the following error

I have restarted the system, RSA, killed all Java process but still getting the same error

```
    [7/9/13 13:03:22:912 CDT] 0000000a WsServerImpl  E   WSVR0009E: Error occurred during      startup
com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError:org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:199)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:140)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:461)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:183)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:90)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:72)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:339)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:94)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:424)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:977)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:673)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:192)
... 24 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.createListener(WSTransport.java:859)
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.initTransports(WSTransport.java:597)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.initTransports(TransportManager.java:158)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1250)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1681)
at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:364)
at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:86)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSServerORBImpl.<init>(EJSServerORBImpl.java:102)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:55)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:417)
... 28 more

[7/9/13 13:03:22:913 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
[7/9/13 13:03:22:913 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:199)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:913 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:140)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:913 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:461)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:913 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:913 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:914 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:914 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:914 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:914 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:183)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:914 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:90)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:914 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:72)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:914 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:914 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:914 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:914 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:914 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:914 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:914 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:914 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:915 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:915 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:915 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:915 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:915 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:339)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:915 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R  at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:94)
[7/9/13 13:03:22:915 CDT] 0000000a SystemErr     R Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeError: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:424)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:977)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:673)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:526)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:192)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:140)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:461)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:183)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:90)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:72)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.runtime.PlatformActivator$1.run(PlatformActivator.java:78)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:92)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:68)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:400)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:177)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:339)
at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:94)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4  vmcid: 0x49421000  minor code: 56  completed: No
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.createListener(WSTransport.java:859)
at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.initTransports(WSTransport.java:597)
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.initTransports(TransportManager.java:158)
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1250)
at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:1681)
at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:364)
at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:86)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:179)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSServerORBImpl.<init>(EJSServerORBImpl.java:102)
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:55)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ORBImpl.start(ORBImpl.java:417)
... 28 more
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

```
Easy Way
```

Open the Task Manager by pressing Ctl+Alt+Del

In the process tab, make sure you check "Show processes from all users"

End all the process with Image Name "java"

```
Hard Way
```

Double click the server in RSA and see the default ports for SOAP etc

in command prompt type "netstat -o"

Note the PID of the process that opening the default ports

Open the task manager
View - > Select Columns -> PID

In the process tab, make sure you check "Show processes from all users"

Find the process by PID and end the process

Answer (score 2):

CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4 almost always means a port conflict.  Check the ports listed in `PROFILE_HOME/config/cells/CELL/nodes/NODE/serverindex.xml` (specifically BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS) and ensure the ports don't conflict with other processes on the same machine.  You can use the `netstat -o` (Windows) or `netstat -p` (Linux) to see which process opened the ports.

Comment: I have the following in serverindex.xml
 <endPoint xmi:id="EndPoint_1351286339514"  host="WPWDRNVB" port="2814"/>

when I run netstat -o I found the following process that has same ports

 TCP    10.37.2.105:**2814**   WPWDRNVB:51054         ESTABLISHED     5620
 TCP    10.37.2.105:51054      WPWDRNVB:**2814**      ESTABLISHED     3596
 TCP    127.0.0.1:**2814**     WPWDRNVB:56542         ESTABLISHED     5620
 TCP    127.0.0.1:56542        WPWDRNVB:**2814**      ESTABLISHED     3596

Do I need to change the port of BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS in the serverindex.xml

Comment: Your netstat output in the comment is nearly unreadable, but no, you should be looking for other LISTEN state. If there are no BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESS conflicts for any server in serverindex.xml, then I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4` It might also happen due to multiple SJE Profiles.

Deleting the profile may solve the problem like it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Last week when i installed, it was working fine. But it stopped with the same error "Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: CREATE_LISTENER_FAILED_4" . However tried all solutions posted in google but didn't work.

I followed the below steps and the websphere started without any issues. Hope this would be helpful to someone in future.

1. In the start menu, search box -> type Services
2. In the Services window, check for IBM Websphere Application server. If the status is in "Start", right click and stop it.
3. Restart your websphere, it works.